# SQLAlchemy inheritance with relationship is None in instantiated object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mixins, single-table-inheritance

I would like to have a 'relationship' in an inherited (mixin) class.

However, when I create the inherited object, the relationship object is None. I cannot append to it.

How do I resolve this?

Here is code based upon the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#mixing-in-relationships)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Boolean, BigInteger, Float
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class Target(Base):
    __tablename__ = "target"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class RefTargetMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def target_id(cls):
        return Column('target_id', ForeignKey('target.id'))

    @declared_attr
    def target(cls):
        return relationship("Target",
            primaryjoin="Target.id==%s.target_id" % cls.__name__
        )

class Foo(RefTargetMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

print repr(RefTargetMixin.target)
print repr(Foo.target)
print repr(Foo().target)
```

The output is:

```
<sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty object at 0x24e7890>
<sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x24e7690>
None
```

In general, I should be able to append to the relationship object (target), but here I cannot because it is None. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour : Foo has one Target. When you create the Foo object, it has no Target yet, so the value of `Foo().target` is `None`.

If you want Foo to have multiple Targets, you should put a `foo_id` in Target, and not a `target_id` in Foo, and use a backref.

Also, in that case, it is not needed to specify the primary join.

Comment: I understand what you're proposing. But it's no an appropriate solution. If I make a class Bar that also subclasses from RefTargetMixin, Target only points to Foo. I want to have *several* subclasses of RefTargetMixin, each of which has a one-to-many-relationship with Target.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want each subclass of `RefTargetMixin` to have many `Target`, is that it ?

Comment: Then what I stand stands. You won't be able to just use mixins in that case, you'll need to use real inheritence. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/declarative.html#inheritance-configuration.

Answer (score 4):

the reason the value is None is because you've defined this as a many-to-one relationship.  Many-to-one, from parent-to-child, means there is a foreign key on the parent, which can only refer to one and only one child.   If you'd like something of class `RefTargetMixin` to refer to a collection of items, then foreign keys must be on the remote side.

So then the goal here is to make any object that is a subclass of RefTargetMixin be a potential parent for a Target.   This pattern is called the [polymorphic association pattern](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2007/05/29/polymorphic-associations-with-sqlalchemy/).   While it is common in many ORM toolkits to provide this by declaring a "polymorphic foreign key" on Target, this is not a good practice relationally, so the answer is to use multiple tables in some way.   There are three scenarios for this provided in SQLAlchemy core in the examples/generic_association folder, including "single association table with discriminator", "table per association", and "table per related".  Each pattern provides the identical declarative pattern for RefTargetMixin here but the structure of the tables changes.

For example, here is your model using "table per association", which in my view tends to scale the best provided you don't need to query multiple types of RefTargetMixin objects at once (note I literally used the example as is, just changed the names):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, \
                    String, ForeignKey, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship

class Base(object):
    """Base class which provides automated table name
    and surrogate primary key column.

    """
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class Target(Base):
    pass

class RefTargetMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def targets(cls):
        target_association = Table(
            "%s_targets" % cls.__tablename__,
            cls.metadata,
            Column("target_id", ForeignKey("target.id"),
                                primary_key=True),
            Column("%s_id" % cls.__tablename__,
                                ForeignKey("%s.id" % cls.__tablename__),
                                primary_key=True),
        )
        return relationship(Target, secondary=target_association)

class Customer(RefTargetMixin, Base):
    name = Column(String)

class Supplier(RefTargetMixin, Base):
    company_name = Column(String)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)

session.add_all([
    Customer(
        name='customer 1',
        targets=[
            Target(),
            Target()
        ]
    ),
    Supplier(
        company_name="Ace Hammers",
        targets=[
            Target(),
        ]
    ),
])

session.commit()

for customer in session.query(Customer):
    for target in customer.targets:
        print target
```